# Recognize user on ASP.NET Site

Tags: .net, asp.net, security

I am looking for an implementation similar to that of what is seen on banking sites.  If a user comes to the site I want them to have to pass some form of registration IE (answer a question or enter in some key).  If the user closes the browser and comes back to the site again from that machine they would just be able to provide login credentails to get in.

I am not sure if this is accomplished in ASP.NET by a cookie or what type of implementation.  Any insight or examples of something similar would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ASP.NET 2.0 Microsoft has put in the **login** controls with which you can authenticate, send forgotten passwords via mail, ...

These controls work closely together with the **Membership provider** API. There are by default already 2 such providers shipping with ASP.NET of which the SqlMembershipProvider is the most popular, and the standard one.

The real power lies in the fact that you can simply create a custom provider and plug it in by configuration if you already have a legacy database.

If you want to learn more about all this good stuff I suggest you take a look at the tutorials you can find here: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/security.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Membership Providers. And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx).